# Need to style heading according to requirements

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to fulfil following requirements:

Display text with formatting

```
<h2 class="heading">
   Hello my dear friends
</h2>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Requirements are next:

1. HTML is immutable
2. Don't use javascript
3. Use sass

I tried to investigate almost all possibilities, but seems I need either edit HTML or add javascript. Can't understand how to use only SASS here, please help, thank you

Comment: So, refer question doesn't answer on how to do it right

The right answer is to use :after and then create an absolute positioned block to heading with particular width and height, and move it back with z-index

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to highlight the 'dear' word? If so you can use `<mark>dear</mark>`

Comment: As I said, I can't change HTML